# Общепринятый символ, обозначающий "ссылка ведет на другой сайт"

Tags: unicode, документация

Пишу документацию к программному продукту.

Хочу отделить ссылки, ведущие на другой сайт, от ссылок внутри того же самого.

На Википедии есть [специальная картинка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), обозначающая такие ссылки. Но это их собственное решение. Есть ли общее и универсальное? Подозреваю, что существует какой-нибудь символ Юникода, но пока что не нашёл ничего лучше, чем `⎆`.

Comment: Разместить favicon сайта на который указывает конкретная ссылка?

Comment: @Visman: там всё внутри гитхаба, но из одной вики ссылки на разные репозитории. А вообще идея хорошая.

Comment: Доп.материал по теме: [Is there a convention for distinguishing internal and external links in a website?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14872/is-there-a-convention-for-distinguishing-internal-and-external-links-in-a-websit) и [External links: Whether & how to distinguishing them from internal links, and to open them](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/external-links-whether-how-to-distinguishing-them-from-internal-links-and-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

судя по всему, *утверждённого* (а, значит, в некотором роде «общепринятого») символа для внешних ссылок в *unicode* нет.

предложение [Proposal to Encode an External Link Sign](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2007/07046-pr-101.html), насколько я понимаю, так пока и остаётся лишь предложением.

---

кстати, у <sup>T</sup><sub>E</sub><sup>X</sup>-нологов по этому поводу, ясное дело, [есть свои варианты](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99316/79376).

Comment: Для внешних ссылок не могут принять, а для [всякого ](http://unicode-table.com/en/1F4A9/) запросто приняли :)